Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information. - React Native
I am trying to build an apk file for my React Native application using the eas build -p android --profile preview command on my physical device. (The dev build built using npx expo run:android works perfectly on my physical device.)
Below are my files:
eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 13.2.3",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

android/build.grade
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '35.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '24')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '35')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.24'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

When I am running the build command, I am getting the below error in my console:
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip
10%
20%.
30%.
40%
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.10.2!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for Java 23
 - Faster configuration cache
 - Better configuration cache reports
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:processResources
NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:shared:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:jar
> Configure project :app
ℹ️  [33mApplying gradle plugin[0m '[32mexpo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin[0m' (expo-dev-launcher@5.0.16)
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - [32mexpo-asset[0m (11.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-blur[0m (14.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-constants[0m (17.0.3)
  - [32mexpo-dev-client[0m (5.0.4)
  - [32mexpo-dev-launcher[0m (5.0.16)
  - [32mexpo-dev-menu[0m (6.0.11)
  - [32mexpo-file-system[0m (18.0.4)
  - [32mexpo-font[0m (13.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-haptics[0m (14.0.0)
  - [32mexpo-json-utils[0m (0.14.0)
  - [32mexpo-keep-awake[0m (14.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-linking[0m (7.0.3)
  - [32mexpo-manifests[0m (0.15.4)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core[0m (2.0.6)
  - [32mexpo-splash-screen[0m (0.29.13)
  - [32mexpo-system-ui[0m (4.0.4)
  - [32mexpo-web-browser[0m (14.0.1)
Errors during XML parse:
Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 35 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 35 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 35 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/35.0.0
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 35 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 35 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 35 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-35
"Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)" finished.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-gesture-handler.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-gesture-handler was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-mmkv.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-mmkv was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-reanimated.
     Required by:
         project :app
> No matching variant of project :react-native-reanimated was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-safe-area-context.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-safe-area-context was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-screens.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-screens was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-svg.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-svg was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-webview.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of project :react-native-webview was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.6.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - No variants exist.
* Try:
> Creating consumable variants is explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:resolvable-consumable-configs.
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
18 actionable tasks: 18 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Now, I am guessing something is to be fixed in my build.gradle file. However, I am unable to figure out what is to be added for the build to be successful.

I fixed my issue by first running npx expo prebuild --clean and then running the build command (eas build -p android --profile preview in my case).

Sometimes, the project might have old artifacts causing issues during the build. Clean the build cache and try rebuilding:
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
eas build -p android

